# Calibration annotation data for Sentinel-1 images downloaded from Sentinel Hub?

Tags: sentinel-1, synthetic-aperture-radar, sar, sentinel-hub, sentinel

I received some Sentinel-1 tiff images that were downloaded via the [WCS service](https://www.sentinel-hub.com/develop/documentation/api/ogc_api/wcs-request), so they're just the tiff files, not the full SAFE-format products.  They're for the IW GRD product, and my understanding from the [documentation](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/product-types-processing-levels/level-1) of that product is that to use the data, you're first supposed to radiometrically calibrate the digital numbers from the tiff files, to get eg backscattering coefficient sigma-naught.  The documentation says that the calibration vectors for doing this conversion are in the Annotation section of the product.  Is there a way to get that information from Sentinel Hub, or maybe to specify when doing the download that we want it to apply the calibration before giving us the file?

Comment: Do you have to use the imagery from the WCS? As in are you looking to generate a workflow based on the process of downloading from the WCS each time...or is this a "one-time" type of process? I would look at downloading the raw imagery from the ESA Website or similar, get the ESA STEP software and follow the "recipes" or tutorials here: https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/toolboxes/sentinel-1/tutorials I have found the tutorials easy to use and learnt a lot.

Comment: Ultimately the goal would be to generate a workflow.  I am not sure why the data we currently have is from the WCS service, maybe we will eventually want the full products, but I wanted to see if there was a way to work with the things we currently have / have a process for getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get sigma-naught, you can use backscatter coefficient parameter (see https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/#/API/data/Sentinel-1-GRD) or configure the Sentinel Hub layer accordingly:

[image: Configuring Sentinel Hub layer with sigma-nought backscatter coefficient]